# Separation angle from single point feature

Tags: qgis, point, line

I have a point feauture (radar). From this radar, I need to draw straight lines with a separation angle of 0.3° (full circle).

At best, I want to draw the first line by myself with all following lines having a separation angle of 0.3° to the first line.

How do I achieve this in QGIS? I tried the Plug-In "Azimuth and Distance" but was not able to solve my issue.

Comment: I am using QGIS 3.28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Processing algorithm `Geometry by Expression`. Set the *Input layer* to your point layer, and chose *Line* for *Output geometry type*.

Use the following expression:

```
collect_geometries(
  array_foreach(
    generate_series(0,360,0.3),
    make_line(
      @geometry,
      project(@geometry,500,radians(@element))
)))
```

It will return a single MultiLineString geometry containing all of the lines. You can then use the Processing algorithm `Multipart to Singleparts` to get the individual lines as separate features.

The second argument of the `project` function (500 in the example) controls the length of the lines.

The result (shown with 5° step so that lines are actually visible):
[image: Result screenshot]